# Node-inspector in node.js: I can't see my source file in the scripts list, but I can see them in the call stack

Tags: debugging, node.js, node-inspector

I can't see my source file in the scripts list, but I can see them in the call stack.

I have made a breakpoint in my source-file but sometimes it just doesn't want to show my source files in the node inspector.. but only sometimes :s that's the problem

anyone knows how to make this work well?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must refresh the browser where you have node inspector started. I think I had the same issue.

Comment: yes, that works. Instead of clicking on the enable debugging button, I refresh and it works. thanks a lot (: